# Plot doesn't appear in my Viewer - Rshiny app - time sliderinput

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, shiny

I started to play with Rshiny to create a dashboard for my athletes. My goal is to get a visualization on my mainPanel, while selecting both Athletes and Date with a select and sliderInput. My tibble Data_GPS_G1 contain several columns, especially Date at  format = d%-m%-y%. Here is my code :

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("RCN Dashboard Visualisation"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h1("JOUEURS"),
      helpText("Sélectionnez un JOUEUR et une PERIODE"),

      selectInput(
        inputId = "Nom",
        label = "Nom :",
        choices = Data_GPS_G1 |>
          pull(Nom) |>
          factor() |>
          levels()
        ),
      sliderInput(
        inputId = "periode",
        label = "Période :",
        min = min(Data_GPS_G1$Date),
        max = max(Data_GPS_G1$Date),
        value = c(min(Data_GPS_G1$Date), max(Data_GPS_G1$Date))      
        )
    ),

    mainPanel(
      "Visualisation GPS - Distances parcourus et Z Scores associés",
      h1(textOutput("selected_nom")),
      tabPanel("Vue d'ensemble", plotOutput("graphique")))
      )
    )


server <- function(input, output) {

   output$selected_nom <- renderText({
     paste("Visualisation de ", input$Nom)
   })

   output$graphique <- renderPlot({
     Data_GPS_G1_filtre <- Data_GPS_G1 %>%
       filter(Date >= input$periode[1] & Date <= input$periode[2])

     a_afficher <- Data_GPS_G1_filtre |>
       ggplot(data = Data_GPS_G1_filtre) +
         aes(x = Date, y = Valeurs, fill = Métriques_Distance) +
         geom_col(color = "black", position = "stack")+
         geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(Valeurs == 0, NA, Valeurs)), color = "black",position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
         geom_label(aes(x = Date, y = Sum_Distance, label = Sum_Distance, fill = NULL), nudge_y = 200, color = "orange", fill = "white")+
         labs(title = "Rapport Distance")+
         coord_flip()+
         theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
               panel.grid = element_blank(),
               legend.position = "none",
               axis.text.x = element_text(vjust = 1,
                                          hjust = 1,
                                          size = 8))
     return(a_afficher)
   })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The app works and the select and slider panels appear. But when I select a name and a period I get this red bold message: Error : [Object object]. See below my glimpse :

```
glimpse(Data_GPS_G1)
Rows: 23,323
Columns: 9
Groups: Nom, Date [4,334]
$ Nom                <chr> "Abescat", "Abescat", "Abescat", "Moise", "Moise", "Tikoi…
$ Métriques_Distance <chr> "Dist 0-5 km/h (m)", "Dist 5-10 km/h (m)", "Dist 10-15 km…
$ Date               <date> 2023-06-19, 2023-06-19, 2023-06-19, 2023-06-19, 2023-06-…
$ Valeurs            <dbl> 869, 418, 3, 897, 426, 875, 402, 1, 722, 112, 781, 366, 9…
$ day                <ord> Mon, Mon, Mon, Mon, Mon, Mon, Mon, Mon, Mon, Mon, Mon, Mo…
$ Moyenne            <dbl> 1453, 788, 480, 1276, 700, 1618, 710, 407, 1473, 607, 166…
$ SD                 <dbl> 500, 465, 305, 517, 276, 582, 154, 212, 562, 265, 480, 23…
$ Z_Score_Distance   <dbl> 1.17, 0.79, 1.57, 0.73, 0.99, 1.28, 2.00, 1.91, 1.34, 1.8…
$ Sum_Distance       <dbl> 1290, 1290, 1290, 1323, 1323, 1278, 1278, 1278, 834, 834,…
```

I think about a Date format issue but I'm not sure.

May someone help me please?

Best regards.

Comment: There is at least one issue with your code: Instead of `a_afficher <- Data_GPS_G1_filtre |> ggplot(data = Data_GPS_G1_filtre) + ` do `a_afficher <- Data_GPS_G1_filtre |> ggplot() +` or `a_afficher <- ggplot(data = Data_GPS_G1_filtre) +`.